# "Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed" Error During Compilation With JDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am working on a project and trying to migrate from compiler ver. from JDK 1.7 to 1.8. I have received the below error on one of the modules during build and I am not able to solve it.

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.6:wsimport (default) on project wae-client-jar: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool failed - check output
```

I am using `IntelliJ` and my `Maven` version is `3.6.3`.

Here is the related part of  my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <packageName>com.company.wae.client.ebif.eps.sopi.wsdl</packageName>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.10</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.company.wae.base</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wae-jboss-lib</artifactId>
                    <version>9.8.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So far I have tried,

-Updating plugin configuration as below

```
 <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
        <packageName>com.company.wae.client.ebif.eps.sopi.wsdl</packageName>
        <vmArgs>
            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
        </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
```

-Changing the version of jaxws-maven-plugin to 2.4.1 and adding below dep. to the plugin

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

-Building the not only that module but whole project as well.

-Deleting jaxws-maven-plugin and jaxws-tools folders from local repo m2.

-Checked the JAVA_HOME path to see if points to JDK1.8. Checked the project SDK (JDK 1.8)

which were all mainly mentioned [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/4).

None of these help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by fixing the errors when `mvn install -e` is used.

- First of all I upgraded the `jaxb-impl` and `jaxb-xjc` versions from `2.1.6` to `2.2.10`.
- I added below `jaxb-core` and `jaxws-tools` dependencies.

Here is the updated part of my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>src/main/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <packageName>com.company.wae.client.ebif.eps.sopi.wsdl</packageName>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.company.wae.base</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wae-jboss-lib</artifactId>
                        <version>9.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```